# importing custom font in Wordpress theme in function.php

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I want to use a custom font (@fontface) in my custom Wordpress. I have brought in google fonts in my functions.php like so

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'Lato', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900', array() );
```

but want to use a font from my fonts folder (theme-name/fonts/...) I am not sure how to do this, I would normally use @fontface... but not sure how it works with Wordpresss

EDIT  I want to bring it in in my functions.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import it using css like so:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900'" />
```

Then it will be accessible to use:

```
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
```

Comment: I want to put it in my functions.php will that line still work?

Comment: Wrap your code above in a function the call it like so: add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'functionname' );

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'give-any-name-to-font-famaly';
src: url('font-name.eot');
src: url('font-name.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('font-name.woff') format('woff'),
url('font-name.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('font-name.svg#font-name') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

to use fonts in css:

```
font-family: 'give-any-name-to-font-famaly';
```